# How to aggregate sales data from header and line tables by month and item?

Tags: powerbi, aggregate, calculated-columns, measure

I'm new to Power BI.  I have two joined tables: sales header with sales document number and date, and sales lines with sales document number, item, and value.  They are joined together by sales document number.  Added columns are performing DAX at the sales document level.  How do I aggregate the data by month, item, and value to add columns with DAX calculations at the aggregation level?

I tried filters and DAX using measures and columns, and filters and DAX using added columns and existing columns.  DAX using measures worked at the month and item level, but I can't figure out how to use aggregate calculations to total the resulting measures.

Comment: If you want time-based aggregation, read up on time intelligence calculations.